# what is the max limit for sending mails on google mail with bots/ per day?

Tags: python, gmail, smtplib

actually, i am trying to send about 400 mails with python smtplib and rendering html in the mail, but after the 98th mail, connection was closed. I know that the time limit for sending google mails per day is 500, so why my connection is closed. actually, there are no errors in the code, it works perfectly, my connection is good and i am using windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case, using smtp.google.com the limit is 100: see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).

It reads:

> Email recipients per day 100* / day for Consumer (e.g., gmail.com) and G Suite free edition.

I do not see any limits for timing.

Comment: yes, but i am not using it directly, i am giving a time limit between each sending about 3 seconds. but the problem may be here. anyway i will try to use paid trial. thanks for the answer

Comment: I updated the link to directly refer to the list of relevant parameters, I hope that helps to clarify the question.

Comment: yes, that helped me. thanks.